# Flutter: How to disable Hero animations for a specific transition

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-navigation

Because I am reusing the same components in different contexts, unwanted Hero animations are displayed in the wrong transitions and my app is looking very glitchy.

This is happening in a rather vanilla project, using `MaterialApp` and `pushNamed` for navigation.

How can I enable or disable these animations in specific transitions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To programmatically disable the Hero animation the flutter has HeroMode Widget

You have to wrap your Hero with a HeroMode and pass a bool value to the `enabled:` parameter

```
HeroMode(
  child: Hero(
  tag: "my-hero",
  ),
  enabled: false, // Your condition here
)
```